# Outer joins with where condition x++

Tags: axapta, x++, ax

I am trying to write a query that retrieves an item based on ItemId or item barcode.

This is using x++, Dynamics AX 2012 R2

```
select firstOnly * from inventTable
where (inventTable.ItemId == _upc || inventItemBarcode.itemBarCode == _upc)
outer join inventItemBarcode 
where inventItemBarcode.itemId == inventTable.ItemId;
```

When this is translated into sql it comes out as...

```
FROM  INVENTTABLE T1 LEFT 
OUTER 
JOIN INVENTITEMBARCODE T2 ON (((T2.PARTITION=?) 
    AND (T2.DATAAREAID=?)) 
    AND (T1.ITEMID=T2.ITEMID)) 
WHERE (((T1.PARTITION=?) 
    AND (T1.DATAAREAID=?)) 
    AND (T1.ITEMID=?))
```

You can see that is is totally omitting the OR condition in the last line.

I tried writing the query like this

```
    select firstOnly * from inventTable
    outer join inventItemBarcode 
    where
        //join
        inventItemBarcode.itemId == inventTable.ItemId
        //ilc
        && (inventTable.ItemId == _upc
        || inventItemBarcode.itemBarCode == _upc);
```

But it puts the OR condition in the outer join ON and then returns me the first row in the InventTable.

Does anyone know how to make this work in X++?

Comment: I think there is something else wrong, because in the SQL statement of your first query, there is no condition on <code>InventItemBarcode.itemBarCode</code> shown. Are you sure that is the sql statement of your first query?

Comment: That's what comes out of the profiler.  Like I said the condition is totally missing when it gets to sql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If using AX 2012 you will have to use [Query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/query.aspx) and [QueryRun](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg923354.aspx) instead, then add your or-expression as a [query expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa893981.aspx) using [addQueryFilter](http://daxmusings.codecrib.com/2011/09/query-and-new-related-objects-in-ax.html).

```
static void Job117(Args _args)
{
    str search = "5705050765989";
    QueryRun qr = new QueryRun(new Query());
    QueryBuildDataSource ds1 = qr.query().addDataSource(tableNum(InventTable));
    QueryBuildDataSource ds2 = ds1.addDataSource(tableNum(InventItemBarcode));
    str qstr1 = '((%1.%2 == "%5") || (%3.%4 == "%5"))';
    str qstr2 = strFmt(qstr1, ds1.name(), fieldStr(InventTable,ItemId), 
                       ds2.name(), fieldStr(InventItemBarcode,ItemBarCode),
                       queryValue(search));
    qr.query().addQueryFilter(ds1, fieldStr(InventTable,ItemId)).value(qstr2);
    ds2.joinMode(JoinMode::OuterJoin);
    ds2.relations(true);
    info(qstr2);
    info(ds1.toString());
    while (qr.next())
        info(strFmt("%1", qr.getNo(1).RecId));
}
```

In prior AX versions you can make a view, then query the view using a query expressions by using the [addRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa592853%28v=ax.50%29.aspx) method.

Comment: Yes I finally came to the same conclusion. It's too bad it can't be done in the query syntax. Thank you for your help.