# How to make X++ query with where clause and OR conditions

Tags: sql, axapta, x++

I try to reproduce a very simple SQL query in **X++** with :

- 3 tables
- where clause
- OR conditions
- LIKE

I would like the following translates result in SQL :

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 tab1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 tab2 on tab2.x = tab1.x
LEFT JOIN TABLE3 tab3 on tab3.x = tab1.x
WHERE (tab1.a LIKE '%F1%' OR tab1.aa LIKE '%F1%' OR tab2.b LIKE '%F1%' or tab3.c LIKE '%F1%')
```

Other example :

```
select   dpt.PARTITION, dpt.recid, * from dirpartytable  dpt
    INNER JOIN DIRPARTYLOCATION dpl on dpl.RECID = dpt.RECID 
    INNER JOIN LOGISTICSLOCATION ll on ll.RECID = dpl.LOCATION
    where (dpt.HOBBIES LIKE '%F21%' OR dpl.POSTALADDRESSROLES LIKE '%F21%'
    OR ll.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%F21%'
```

Other internet example :

```
FieldId itemIdField = fieldNum(InventTable, ItemId);
FieldId itemTypeField = fieldNum(InventTable, ItemType);
Query query1 = new Query();
QueryBuildDataSource ds1 = query1.addDataSource(tableNum(InventTable));
ds1.addRange(itemIdField).value('Item01');
ds1.addRange(itemIdField).value('Item02');
ds1.addRange(itemIdField).value('(ItemId > "Item04")');
ds1.addRange(itemTypeField).value(queryValue(ItemType::Item));
ds1.addRange(itemTypeField).value(queryValue(ItemType::Service));
query1.addQueryFilter(ds1, itemIdField).value('Item02');
query1.addQueryFilter(ds1, itemIdField).value('Item03');
query1.addQueryFilter(ds1, itemIdField).value('(ItemId < "Item01")');
query1.addQueryFilter(ds1, itemTypeField).value(queryValue(ItemType::Service));
```

give this :

```
SELECT *
FROM INVENTTABLE T1
WHERE PARTITION=68719480489
 AND DATAAREAID='dat'
 AND (ITEMID='Item01' OR ITEMID='Item02' OR ITEMID>'Item04')
 AND (ITEMTYPE=0 OR ITEMTYPE=2)
 AND (ITEMID='Item02' OR ITEMID='Item03' OR ITEMID<'Item01')
 AND (ITEMTYPE=2)
ORDER BY T1.ITEMTYPE, T1.ITEMID
```

what i'm expected is almost the same but with "OR"conditions based on multiples fields from other tables.

I tried addRange and addQueryFilter but the result is not good.

```
           QueryBuildDataSource tab1;
           QueryBuildDataSource tab2;
           QueryBuildDataSource tab3;       

            tab1 = query.dataSourceTable(tableNum(TABLE1)); 
            tab2 = query.dataSourceTable(tableNum(TABLE2));
            tab3 = query.dataSourceTable(tableNum(TABLE3));                    
            
            **// 1 - ADDQUERYFILTER**
            query.addQueryFilter(tab1, fieldStr(TABLE1, a)).value('F1');
            query.addQueryFilter(tab1, fieldStr(TABLE1,aa)).value('F1');
            query.addQueryFilter(tab2, fieldStr(TABLE2,b)).value('F1');
            query.addQueryFilter(tab3, fieldStr(TABLE3, c)).value('F1') 
            
             **// 2 - ADDRANGE**
             QueryBuildRange qbr; 
             qbr = tab1.addRange(fieldNum(TABLE1, a));
             qbr = tab1.addRange(fieldNum(TABLE1, aa));
             qbr = tab2.addRange(fieldNum(TABLE2, b));
             qbr = tab3.addRange(fieldNum(TABLE3, c));
             qbr.value(strFmt('((%2 LIKE \'%%1%\') || (%3 LIKE \'%%1%\') || (%4 LIKE \'%%1%\') || (%5 LIKE \'%%1\'))', 'F1', fieldStr(TABLE1, a), fieldStr(TABLE1, aa) fieldStr(TABLE2, b), fieldStr(TABLE3, c) ));
```

I'm lost, how to do it in X++?

Thanks.

Comment: Your table names makes it hard to test. Could you specify it using standard AX tables?

Comment: Jan B. Kjeldsen
 I've add an another example

Comment: Did you try your 2 example? It is not correct, `on dpl.RECID = dpt.RECID` should be `on dpl.PARTY = dpt.RECID` , also `HOBBIES` and `POSTALADDRESSROLES` are not standard fields.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to X++ and not very good in english, I don't know what the standard tables and fields are, I juste try to give an example of what I expect for a query in X++ and the translate result in SQL.
It's why I give example with random tables names, I just want to know if it's possible to make a X++ query with several filters based on differents tables and with "OR" conditions.

Comment: Well it is possible using query expressions, just your example makes no sense. I will link to some other ...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24416088/outer-joins-with-where-condition-x/24427639#24427639

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42712230/modify-query-string-on-a-form-to-add-filter-based-on-other-fields/42712766#42712766

Comment: If you cannot test your examples it is difficult verify any solution. This is no beginner topic so maybe focus on concrete examples in the AX code base.

Comment: Thanks for the example I almost want to do the same query but in the "WHERE" clause I expect OR conditions and another fields from another tables. I add an another example in my post

Comment: What version of Dynamics are you using? There is a [like](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/dev-ref/xpp-operators#the-like-operator) operator that also works in expressions for the `where` part of a `select` statement. So I don't think you need to use query expressions (and as far as I know, you can't use `LIKE` in them anyway).

Comment: You can use use `like` in query expressions from AX 2009 onwards: `(Name like "*opt*")`.  
You will need query expressions in a query but not in X++. Due to `or` on different fields.

Answer (score 3):

X++ using `while select` [statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/dev-ref/xpp-data/xpp-while-select) (more syntax [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/dev-ref/xpp-data/xpp-select-statement)):

```
Table1 tab1;
Table2 tab2;
Table3 tab3;
while select tab1
   outer join tab2 
   where tab2.x == tab1.x
   outer join tab3 
   where tab3.x  == tab1.x && (
         tab1.a  like '*F1*' || 
         tab1.aa like '*F1*' || 
         tab2.b  like '*F1*' || 
         tab3.c  like '*F1*')
{
    info(strFmt('%1 %2', tab1.x, tab1.a));
}
```

Update: parentheses are important.